# Powershell: get DHCP status with Get-NetIPConfiguration?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a powershell newbie.

If I run `Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed` I can see the IPv4 DHCP status. This is a good start - took me a lot of googling to get this far:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed

ComputerName                          : VM-172-26-39-24
InterfaceAlias                        : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex                        : 6
InterfaceDescription                  : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter
NetCompartment.CompartmentId          : 1
NetCompartment.CompartmentDescription : Default Compartment
NetAdapter.LinkLayerAddress           : FA-16-3E-FF-0D-60
NetAdapter.Status                     : Up
NetProfile.Name                       : Network
NetProfile.NetworkCategory            : Public
NetProfile.IPv6Connectivity           : NoTraffic
NetProfile.IPv4Connectivity           : Internet
IPv6LinkLocalAddress                  : fe80::x:x:x:x
IPv4Address                           : 172.26.39.249
IPv6DefaultGateway                    :
IPv4DefaultGateway                    : 172.26.36.1
NetIPv6Interface.NlMTU                : 9000
NetIPv4Interface.NlMTU                : 9000
NetIPv6Interface.DHCP                 : Enabled
NetIPv4Interface.DHCP                 : Disabled
DNSServer                             : x.x.x.x
                                        x.x.x.x
```

But if I run something like 
`Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select InterfaceAlias,NetIPv4Interface.DHCP`

I get an empty field?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | `
select InterfaceAlias, NetIPv4Interface.DHCP

InterfaceAlias NetIPv4Interface.DHCP
-------------- ---------------------
Ethernet
```

Am I doing something wrong?

If I remove the trailing .DHCP ("what's in there?") I see nothing recognisable

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | select InterfaceAlias, NetIPv4Interface

InterfaceAlias NetIPv4Interface
-------------- ----------------
Ethernet       MSFT_NetIPInterface (Name = "@55?55;", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the sub property when used in a Select statement:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed | `
select InterfaceAlias, @{N="DHCP";E={$_.NetIPv4Interface.DHCP}}
```

Or try this:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | Select -ExpandProperty NetIPv4Interface | Select InterfaceAlias,DHCP
```

...or you could just retrieve the config, put it in a variable then get the desired sub-properties:

```
$Config = Get-NetIPConfiguration

$Config | forEach {
    [pscustomobject]@{InterFaceAlias=$_.InterFaceAlias;DHCP=$_.NetIPv4Interface.DHCP}
}
```